# Filterable mode "row" with data string array

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

I have a kendo grid with datasource which have data string array.
I want use the option mode row and filter on fiel organizations but it doesn't work because it wait a string not a array.
The error is : "TypeError: (intermediate value).toLowerCase is not a function"

I have a exmaple here : https://dojo.telerik.com/@lgoubet/ETOXoFot

Here my code :

```
   var organizations_arr = ['org1', 'org2', 'org3', 'org4'];
  var data = [
    {
      Name: 'abc',
      Organizations: ["org1, org4"]
    },
    {
      Name: 'def',
      Organizations:['org3']
    }
  ];



  function orgEditor(container, options) {
    $("<select multiple='multiple' data-bind='value:Organizations'/>")
.appendTo(container)
.kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: organizations_arr,
      valuePrimitive: true,
        value: options.model.Organizations
});
  }


  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        data: data
      },
      filterable: {
        mode: "row"
      },

      sortable: true,
      editable: true,
      columns: [{
        field: "Name",
        width: 200
      }, {
        field: "Organizations",
        width: 150,
        template: "#= Organizations.join(', ') #",

        editor: orgEditor
      }]
    });
```

Do you have a solution ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: [This is the closest I could get](https://dojo.telerik.com/atuzaLah), but I don't think it is ok tho.

Comment: I had the very same issue and ended up creating another property which is a simple string. I guess that's the way to go in this case.

Comment: and it works with kendoMultiSelect ? do you have a sample ?